# Having many issues trying to dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 7

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7

I am currently trying to dual boot Ubuntu 12.04 LTS along with Windows 7 on my computer, but am running into a problem. Ubuntu installer cannot seem to see my Windows 7. These are the only choices I get.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTcyz.png

Is there anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what might cause the Ubuntu installer to be unable to detect your Windows 7 partitions, but for now you can select "Something Else" and manually select your install method.

You should shrink your Windows partitions and create free space, then create a new `ext4` partition to be formatted with `/` as mount point.

Comment: I did that, but then I got this pop up. http://i.imgur.com/aVcy4Tn.png

Comment: That is strange, I don't know how to help you for that. Sorry :(